# How to enumerate the items in line within the paragraph not each item in a separate line?

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs, enumitem

I want to have the following:

```
A graph can be cut in several ways including 
\begin {enumerate*} [label=\itshape\alph*\upshape)]
\item minimum cut, \item normalised cut and \item average cut. 
\end {enumerate*} 
In our project we have surveyed the Normalised Cut (Ncut)  algorithm for image segmentation.
```

A graph can be cut in several ways including 1) minimum cut, 2) normalised cut and 3) average cut. In our project we have surveyed the Normalised Cut (Ncut)  algorithm for image segmentation.

Answer (score 20):

You'll get an inline enumerated list if you (a) load the `enumitem` package with the `inline` option and (b) use the `enumerate*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
A graph can be cut in several ways including 
\begin {enumerate*} [label=\itshape\alph*\upshape)]
\item minimum cut, \item normalised cut and \item average cut. 
\end {enumerate*} 
In our project we have surveyed the Normalised Cut (Ncut)  algorithm for image segmentation.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

With the `enumitem` package and the `inline`option, it's easy. Use the `shortlabels` option to have a simpler way to format your labels, just like the  `enumerate` package. Note that no punctuation is necessary: it is the environment that takes care of it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textheight = 24cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{itemjoin ={,\enspace},itemjoin* = { and\enspace}}

\begin{document}

A graph can be cut in several ways including
\begin {enumerate*} [1) ]%
\item minimum cut \item normalised cut \item average cut.
\end {enumerate*}
In our project we have surveyed the Normalised Cut (Ncut)  algorithm for image segmentation.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that your screenshot doesn't correspond fully to the code you posted. (E.g.,  note the double instance of "and".) Please fix when it's convenient for you. Good news: your code still works. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Roll your own `inlineenum` environment, if you are so inclined:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{inlineenum}
\renewcommand{\theinlineenum}{\alph{inlineenum}}
\newenvironment{inlineenum}
  {\unskip\ignorespaces\setcounter{inlineenum}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\item}{\refstepcounter{inlineenum}{\textit{\theinlineenum})~}}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}

A graph can be cut in several ways including
\begin{inlineenum}
  \item minimum cut,
  \item normalised cut and
  \item average cut. 
\end{inlineenum}
In our project we have surveyed the Normalised Cut (Ncut)  algorithm for image segmentation.

\end{document}
```